# If x-axis labels are string values then they are not showing up in d3 chart

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am having one d3 scatter chart. It is working fine if I will give numeric value for x and y axis. But if x-axis contains string values then nothing is getting shown up in chart.

```
var data = [[Project1,3], [Project2,17]];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 15, bottom: 60, left: 60}
  , width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right
  , height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
          .range([ 0, width ]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
          .range([ height, 0 ]);

var chart = d3.select('#cognitiveChartDiv')
.append('svg:svg')
.attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.attr('class', 'chart')

var colors = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([5, 20])
.range(['#4577bc','#4577bc'])

var main = chart.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.attr('class', 'main')   

// draw the x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient('bottom');

main.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
.attr('class', 'main axis date')
.call(xAxis);

// draw the y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient('left');

main.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
.attr('class', 'main axis date')
.call(yAxis);

var g = main.append("svg:g"); 

g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[0]); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )
      .attr("r", 8)
      .style('stroke', function(d,i) {
        return colors(i);
    })
    .style('fill', function(d,i) {
        return colors(i);
    })
```

If `var data = [[1,10],[2,20]]` then it is working as expected. I want the chart to work for string value as well. Please suggest me what I should do. I have tried to use `ordinal()` function in place of linear function, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"If x-axis labels are string values..."*. Actually, the axes labels are **always** strings.

You have a different question, as you describe in the body: you want to pass strings as well in your data array. That being the case, you have to change the scale. Specifically, an ordinal scale:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d[0];
  }))
  .rangePoints([0, width], 0.5)
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var data = [
  ["Project1", 3],
  ["Project2", 17]
];

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 15,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d[0];
  }))
  .rangePoints([0, width], 0.5)

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d[1];
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var chart = d3.select('#cognitiveChartDiv')
  .append('svg:svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .attr('class', 'chart')

var colors = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([5, 20])
  .range(['#4577bc', '#4577bc'])

var main = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('class', 'main')

// draw the x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient('bottom');

main.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .attr('class', 'main axis date')
  .call(xAxis);

// draw the y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient('left');

main.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
  .attr('class', 'main axis date')
  .call(yAxis);

var g = main.append("svg:g");

g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return x(d[0]);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("r", 8)
  .style('stroke', function(d, i) {
    return colors(i);
  })
  .style('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors(i);
  })
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="cognitiveChartDiv"></div>
```